# IIS rewrite rule to get domain without tld

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5

Looking to create a working IIS rewrite (not a redirect) rule to rewrite http{s}://www.**client1**.com/page1.htm to https://**client1**.mysite.com/myapp/**client1**/page1.htm - I just can't get it working. Driving me a little mad.

My main problem is getting the domain name WITHOUT the TLD part returned as an R{x} or C{x} parameter...

Note the client name is in two places in the target url - AND Note that the original url could be *client2.com* or *client3.org* or *client4.net*

Answer (score 0):

This rule will rewrite it for you:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite clients domains" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)\.(\w+)$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{MapProtocol:{HTTPS}}://{C:2}.mysite.com/myapp/{C:2}/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="MapProtocol">
        <add key="on" value="https" />
        <add key="off" value="http" />
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```